# How to handle session in Clojure web application tests written with ring-mock?

Tags: unit-testing, session, clojure, ring

In my application, I need a functionality where one request fetches a token(random string) from the server which is stored in the session and the second request is made with this token.

When I make the requests in my tests using [ring-mock](https://github.com/weavejester/ring-mock), the second request says the token is not in session. I assume both requests are independent in test scenario.

How do I maintain a session when issuing multiple requests using ring-mock for writing tests? Or is there any other library that I can use for tests in such cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the suggestion by James Reeves through twitter, I was able to solve this problem by using [peridot](https://github.com/xeqi/peridot). It has session handling for writing tests.